# Is there a way to call a method inside an NSTextView when a Mac OSX 10.4 program is launched?

Tags: objective-c, macos, launch

I'm trying to make a Mac OSX program in Objective-C, and I'm trying to call a method inside an `NSObject` when the program is launched (opened by the user). I've tried so many different things. I'm still stuck on this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question is quite vague. Are you using the Cocoa AppKit framework or are you trying to write a simple command-line tool using Objective-C? In the former, write an `-applicationDidFinishLaunching:` method in your application delegate class and it will be called when, well when the app finishes launching. In the later case, just add code to your `main()` method.

Comment: I think that's what I'm looking for :)

Comment: Yes, this method has been in AppKit since OS X 10.0

Comment: Ok. Do I just add it to @implementation and @interface? How do I call it?

Comment: @SamH, add it to the @implementation of the class of your NSApplication's `delegate`. Start with the Application Architecture Overview (http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/AppArchitecture/AppArchitecture.html%23//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000005i).

Answer (score 0):

You can try notify_post("com.yourcompany.yourapp.themethod").

Or, just include the header of the NSObject and init, call the method.